# Need htaccess expert > Redirect to subdirectory + rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I got some knowledge with htaccess, but when I have to manage subfolders, the problem becomes too complicate for me.

---

**A) Is it possible to get this result with htaccess ?**

The **raw URL** typed by the visitor in the address bar is :

```
https://www.exemple.com/swiss/
```

The **file open** on his browser is :

```
https://www.exemple.com/swiss/page/helvetia.html
```

BUT the **URL show in the address bar** is :

```
https://www.exemple.com/switzerland/
```

If it's not possible to resolve this with htaccess, maybe simply show this URL at least :

```
https://www.exemple.com/swiss/
```

---

I search the web for solutions, but this one is above my level. Thank you a lot for your time. All the best !

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: These are two separate things you are asking for here. Getting the address bar to show `/switzerland/` when `/swiss/` was requested, that requires an external redirect first of all. And then you want to internally rewrite the request for `/switzerland/` to `/swiss/page/helvetia.html`